# JS/JQUERY How to give priority to a button click in the same DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

My whole div is clickable and will change the page. However, inside my div, I have an element that is also clickable, but it should be prioritized sincee it stays on the page.

Basicly, i'm working on a webshop. clicking on a div will go to a new page with the requested data. However, the div includes a clickable image that adds the item to the wishlist.

In the code below, child refers to my whole clickable div, whereas my wishElement is the clickable image to refer to my wishlist.

```
            $('#' + wishElement).click(function() {
          window.location.href = "http://website.com/index.php?wish=" + child;
        });

        $('#' + child).click(function(){
          window.location = "http://website.com/item.php?item=" + child + '&name=' + itemname +  '&link=' + link;
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `event.stopPropagation();` to stop your child event from bubbling up:

```
$('#' + child).click(function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
    window.location = "http://website.com/item.php?item=" + child + '&name=' + itemname +  '&link=' + link;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However this is not what i'm looking for, appoligies.
The div has to remain clickable to go to my new page with requested details.
I need to be able to click both div and image, but if i click the image, dont execute the div click. And if i click the div, then still do what it was designed to do so.

Comment: @gauthiercremers that's exactly what's suggested - If my eyes are not cheating...

Comment: Tried your code, result: 
click on image => does what my child does
click on DIV => does what my child does

What i would like:
click on image => does what my image does
click on DIV => does what my child does

Comment: @gauthiercremers - can you make an example? I still believe the above should work..

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been solved by the post coded above, however, the

> ev.stopPropagation();

has to be inside my wishElement in order to work.

So thanks for the help!